# how to update fields for all rows using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a question table in my database with an attribute(field) "flag". In my c# program I want to update the field "flag" and set it to false for all data rows in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL/Sql Server

```
UPDATE databaseName.tableName SET flag = false;
```

That will set the column to false for each row in the table

I think for Sql Server it will be 0 instead of false

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 and I want to update it in my code behind page of asp.net using c#

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx You will just need to make a sqlcommand and execute that query

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the objects in your c# code you can simply do:

```
foreach(Question currentQuestion in QuestionList)
{
    currentQuestion.flag = false;
}
```

and then save the QuestionList however you interact with the database, for example, entity framework would be

```
UpdateMultiple<Question>(questionList);
```

If you are working directly in sql server, then you would do

```
Update Questions
    Set flag = 0
```

Comment: I recommend, "Update Questions set flag = 0 where 1=1" if you do this, no-one (including yourself) this you just forgot the where clause when they see this later.